# Parse MapView pin

Tags: parse-platform, mapkit, mkannotationview

In my app I have a map in which I view all of the city directly by Parse . Now I would use different images to identify them . These images are loaded on my database Parse . How can I see these images ? thanks to all I hope I was clear . This is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];



PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Citta"];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

    if (!error)
    {

        NSLog(@"QUERY -----> :%@", objects);


        for(NSMutableDictionary *note1 in objects) {
            float realLatitude1 = [[note1 objectForKey:@"Lat"] doubleValue];
            float realLongitude1 = [[note1 objectForKey:@"Lon"] doubleValue];

            NSLog(@"(PARSE) Lat: %f", realLatitude1);
            NSLog(@"(PARSE) Lon: %f", realLongitude1);


            MKPointAnnotation *displayMap = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];

            CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
            theCoordinate.latitude = realLatitude1;
            theCoordinate.longitude = realLongitude1;
            displayMap.coordinate = theCoordinate;
            displayMap.title = [note1 objectForKey:@"Nome_citta"];
            displayMap.subtitle = [note1 objectForKey:@"Nome_regione"];
            //displayMap.icon = [note1 objectForKey:@"icona"];
            [self.mapView setDelegate:self];
            [self.mapView addAnnotation:displayMap];


        }
    }

}];
```

}

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
        viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
```

{
    static NSString *falesieIdentifier = @"falesie";
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:falesieIdentifier];
    if (annotationView == nil) {
        annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                      reuseIdentifier:falesieIdentifier];

```
    annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"marker.png"];

    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;




   // UIButton *detailButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

    UIImageView *carView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UITableNext"]];

    UIButton *blueView = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 44+30)];
    blueView.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xffffff);
    [blueView addTarget:self action:@selector(prepareForSegue:sender:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    carView.frame = CGRectMake(23, 19, carView.image.size.width, carView.image.size.height);
    [blueView addSubview:carView];

    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = blueView;
        }



        return annotationView;
    }
```

Comment: the images are stored in PFFiles? you aren't explaining what your code does wrong...

Comment: yes the image are stored in PFFiles, I want to know how to load PFFile on the map

Answer (score 0):

You should probably download all of the PFFiles in advance so that when you create the map annotations you can replace your `annotationView.image` line with loading the image from the downloaded file data rather than from a static image by name.